# What's the SSD producer with cheapest warranty/return policy?

Tags: ssd, warranty

When I compare prices of HDDs, I embed a virtual "warranty price" for the costs I'd find if I needed a return (assuming the producer provides more than 2-year EU commercial warranty). Which producer has the lowest ones (for an EU customer)?

The return/RMA policies aren't always clear or easy to find. For instance:

- http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/SSD/global/html/support/warranty.html + http://www.samsung.com/us/support/supportServiceWarrantySSDODDExchange.do
- http://www.kingston.com/it/company/warranty#procedures
- http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/company-warranty

Samsung is the only one whose policy doesn't explicitly say the costs for shipping to the service centre are on the customer. Does "pack the drive [...] include the completed XRA form, and ship insurance and freight pre-paid to the SAMSUNG address on the XRA form" mean that the XRA (Exchange Return Authorization) comes with a prepaid shipping label, or what? They also have a clause stating that if no issue is found on the drive then the customer has to reimburse Samsung the shipping expenses, but it's not clear *which* shipping expenses they're talking of.

Comment: If you're looking for a recommendation based on a warranty, you'll still need to include other requirements for the SSD you want. If you aren't looking for a recommendation, this question doesn't fit on this site.

Comment: @Adam, what sort of requirements? I'm asking for a producer recommendation; I think all producers are the same when it comes to other requirements so it wouldn't help much to say I want a SATA 2.5" 250 GB or whatever.

Comment: So you're asking for a recommendation of a manufacturer and not a product?

Comment: @Adam seems like it. I'd be prepared to give this question a chance, could be interesting.